# Remove navigation bar from WPF Pages application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF/XAML Window that navigates different Pages. The navigation is performed this way:

```
MainFrame.Navigate(new LoginPage(this));
```

The problem is that, at the first navigation, a bar appears on top of the Window:

[image]

How can I remove/hide it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1.
In your Frame Tag Add the Event ContentRendered. as

```
 <Frame Name="myFrame" ContentRendered="myFrame_ContentRendered" ></Frame>
```

Step 2.
In the ContentRendered event handler set the  NavigationUIVisibility Hidden for each page instead on calling the same on all the pages as.

```
     private void myFrame_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myFrame.NavigationUIVisibility = System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;
    }
```

or simply use :  `<Frame Source="YOURPAGE.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Navigation window,
Please use it.

ShowsNavigationUI="False"